# Repeated audio clip not playing - Java

Tags: java, audio

I have a scheduled thread that runs every half-second or so and plays an audio clip each time, calling `stop()` on the clip before each cycle in order to `start()` it again:

```java
public AudioThread() {
    Clip clipF5 = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream inputF5 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("sound.wav"));
    clipF5.open(inputF5);
}

ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (clipF5.isRunning()) { clipF5.stop(); }

        clipF5.start();
    }
}, 1, interval, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
```

But it doesn't play again after the first time. The code runs, but the sound doesn't play. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to fix!

You just need to add the step of resetting the media position. You can do this with either `clip.setFramePosition(0)` or `clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0)` to go back to the beginning of the clip. The start() method simply starts from the last media position, even if it is the end of the file.

```
if (clipF5.isRunning()) 
{
    clipF5.stop(); 
    clipF5.setFramePosition(0);
}

clipF5.start();
```

I'm assuming the length of your clip is less than 30 seconds!